Save spark dataframe as table using abfs path
I know I can use "path" option along with saveAsTable to specify a non-default lakehouse for my table:
  dataframe\
        .write\
        .format("delta")\
        .mode("overwrite")\
        .partitionBy("year", "month")\
        .option("path", f'abfss://WORKSPACE_NAME@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/LAKEHOUSE_NAME.Lakehouse/Tables/')\
        .saveAsTable(TABLE_NAME)

I was expecting the table appearing under "Tables" folder and all the underlying partitions associated with the table. Instead, while the table is created, its "_delta_log" and all the partitions exist separately under "Unidentified" folder.

  dataframe\
    .write\
    .format("delta")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .partitionBy("year", "month")\
    .option("path", f'abfss://WORKSPACE_NAME@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/LAKEHOUSE_NAME.Lakehouse/Tables/TABLE_NAME')\
    .saveAsTable(TABLE_NAME)

adding the name of the table at the end of the path worked. There is also an easier way to save to a non-default lakehouse without absf:
   dataframe\
        .write\
        .format("delta")\
        .mode("overwrite")\
        .partitionBy("year", "month")\
        .saveAsTable(LAKEHOUSE_NAME.TABLE_NAME)

